# Whether to use WebSocket or Server Sent Event for sending notifications from server which retrieves social network presence in realtime?

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, server-sent-events, communication-protocol

i want to develop a webpage which retrieves from server and shows online presence information of user's contact from various social sites like facebook, google & skype, linked in real time should i use WebSocket or Server Sent Event (SSE) ?

The web application needs to support older browsers and would be deployed over cloud to server 1000s of concurrent users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back to the basics. According to this page here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp , Internet Explorer does not support SSE. So maybe there's a plugin that can wrap both functions for use in different browsers. Otherwise WebSocket. Your choice though.